# Flash CS5.5-AIR i cant write HTML tags with writeUTFBytes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe, flash-cs5

i need to write some XML using AIR from Flash CS5.5
My code works, but i dont know how to write some html tags without flash converting < to ; & gt;
I want to write HTML code for a .
How can i achieve that?

This is the type of code i am using, im working into an AIR from Flash CS5.5

Everything works fine except i dont get the "<" but the ;& gt; in the outputfile and the same for many of the HTML signs like > etc.

```
    function SaveFile(event:MouseEvent){
var objs:XML = new XML( <objects /> );
var ball1:XML = <ball />.appendChild(input_text.text); 
// In the input i want to write the CDATA and the HTML text dynamically each time
ball1.@xPos = 12; 
ball1.@yPos = 42; 
objs.appendChild( ball1 ); 


var vFile = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('file.xml');
var vStream = new FileStream();
vStream.open(vFile, FileMode.WRITE);
vStream.writeUTFBytes(objs);
vStream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `String` to the `appendChild` function and that's why you got your result as a "text" in your xml file. So to avoid that, you have just to pass an `XML` object instead of the `String` :

```
// ...

var ball1:XML = <ball />.appendChild(new XML(input_text.text)); 

// ...
```

**EDIT :**

To add the XML declaration to your XML file, you can use a [`XMLDocument`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/xml/XMLDocument.html) like this :

```
// ...

objs.appendChild(ball1); 

var xml_document:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(objs.toXMLString());
    xml_document.xmlDecl = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n';

var file = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('file.xml');
var file_stream = new FileStream();
    file_stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    file_stream.writeUTFBytes(xml_document.toString());
    file_stream.close();
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Excellent, did you know how to put the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> at the beggining?